# How to use Seven segment in UnoArduSim

Tags: arduino, simulation, seven-segment-display

I'm a beginner studying programming and am using UnoArduSim (an Arduino Simulation). I'm still confused by how to use the Seven Segment module because there are only 2 addresses namely the address to the pin and cs *.

How do you use it and how is the program syntax?

[image: image of the arduino simulator]

Answer (score 1):

In the menu bar of that program there is something called "Help".
Why don't you click it?

> **7-Segment LED Digit  ('7SEG')**  You can connect this 7-Segment Digit
>   LED display to a  chosen set of four consecutive 'Uno' pins that give
>   the hexadecimal code for the desired displayed digit, ('0' through
>   'F'), and turn this digit on or off using the CS* pin (active-LOW for
>   ON). This device includes a built-in decoder which uses the
>   active-HIGH levels on the four consecutive '1of4' pins to determine
>   the requested hexadecimal digit to be displayed . Te level on the
>   lowest pin number (the one displayed in the '1of4'  edit box)
>   represents the least-significant bit of the 4-bit hexadecimal code.
>   The colour of the LED segments ('R', 'Y', 'G', or 'B') is a hidden
>   option that can be only be chosen by editing the  IODevices.txt file
>   you can create using Save from the Configure | 'I/O' Devices
>   dialog-box.

Please read manuals.

### Edit:

As you don't seem to understand the description, here's a simple example that displays digits 0 to 9. The digit is incremented every second.

[image]

```
/*  This is a default program--
    Use File->Load Prog to load a different program
*/   

void setup()
{
    for (int i  = 3; i <= 8; i++)
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{
    // display a new digit every second
    for (int digit = 0; digit <= 9; digit++)
    {
        for (int pin = 4; pin <= 7; pin++)
            digitalWrite(pin, (bool)(digit & (1 << pin - 4)));
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have read  the manual, but still confused. Are there any tutorials and simple program code examples for running seven segments on UnoArduSim ?

Comment: it's just a simulator. any arduino tutorial will do. you only need to know how to set digital outputs

Comment: In Arduino uses 7 ports, while in UnoArduSIM only 2 ports for seven segments. I have not gotten a code sample that uses 2 ports on Arduino for the seven segment.

Comment: @Zacknov please read my answer or the manual! 1of4 names the first of four consecutive outputs. let's say pins 4 to 7. to display a 7 you set 4 high, 5 high, 6 high, 7 low.

Comment: @Zacknov of course it works. the question is, do you understand it...

Comment: Could you please explain in detail to me about the syntax :

 digitalWrite(pin, (bool)(digit & (1 << pin - 4)));

Comment: @Zacknov it set sets the output value of the respective pin according to the digit to be displayed. I cannot teach you basic C++ through this post.

Comment: This might be about Left shift and Right shift operations. Thank you very much, I will study C / C ++ again.

Comment: yes you have to find out if the bits of your number are 1 or 0 so you can set your outputs accordingly.

Comment: can this program be implemented in Arduino? how is the circuit

Comment: @Zacknov of course that's why this is an Arduino Simulator... just search the web for "7 segment arduino" is it really so difficult?

Comment: I mean, arduino with unoardusim (arduino simulator) is not the same. 7 segments on Arduino devices are not the same as 7 segments on Unoardusim devices. Because the Arduino device uses 7 pins, while Unoardusim only has 1 pin. Correct that?

Comment: unoardusim uses 4 pins. you just define those 4 pins by entering the first of four pins number... you can use a BCD to 7 segment decoder IC and do exactly the same